# Why does running the Jekyll theme so-simple look nothing like the theme examples (e.g. missing home buttons and logo)?

Tags: rubygems, jekyll, jekyll-theme

I am using the [so-simple theme](https://github.com/mmistakes/so-simple-theme) by Michael Rose, which I created by adding this to my Jekyll site's `Gemfile`:

`gem "jekyll-theme-so-simple"`

And this to my Jekyll site's `config.yml` file:

`theme: jekyll-theme-so-simple`

I then ran Bundler to install the dependencies with:

`bundle install`

Now, running `bundle exec jekyll serve` adds the Jekyll theme to my site... but only somewhat. This is what it produces:

["so-simple" on my site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f0KfA.png)

Clearly, this is using the theme as the font and layout are changing, but it is missing the home buttons, the logo placement, and almost every key part of the theme that I was wishing to add.

This is what the theme is supposed to look like:

[so-simple demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZhVnZ.png)

Why am I unable to replicate the layout of the theme? And how could I run the `/example`  folder for so-simple to build off of that particular layout?

Answer (score 0):

From the details here, it's `_config.yml` (with an underscore). If that doesn't work, you could provide a GitHub repo link.